# WSS Socket on EC2 instance with Load Balancer and Certificate Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, sockets, ssl-certificate, amazon-elb, aws-certificate-manager

I'm trying to set up a solution which includes an EC2 instance with Apache running NodeJS. I've already successfully created a working webserver-instance with a public SSL-certificate from Certifate Manager accessed on port 80 and 443. This server should be able to connect to my other instance but for some reason I keep running into dead-ends and I suspect the solution is not possible...

I've built a working setup using Let's Encrypt certificates but I would love to keep as much as possible in AWS.

*Issue:*
In the LE-solution, I can access the local .pem-files on my server. I can include the local paths to the LE-certificates in the server-setup-file like this:

```
...

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem")
};

var https   = require('https').Server(options, app);

...
```

but when I'm using AWS Certificate Manager's public certificates, I'm not sure how to get around this?

*My solution (not working):*
I'm no SSL-wizard, so I might be trying to do something impossible here. I've tried to create a local certificate using OpenSSL but keep the Load Balancer and Certificate Manager certificate on the domain.

```
...

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("/home/ec2-user/server-key.pem"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("/home/ec2-user/server-cert.pem"),
};

var https   = require('https').Server(options, app);

...
```

This solutions returns following error message when I try to connect to the node/socket server with url: `https://live.example.com:3000`:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://live.example.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

So I guess that my solution with both Certificate Manager certificate on the domain and the OpenSSL certificate on the server isn't possible or is the problem to be found elsewhere?

Please let me know :-)

Comment: Are you ok with using the AWS cert on a load balancer and having plain HTTP connections between the load balancer and your Apache server?

Comment: @DylanSp because you have a suggestion for a working solution or are you pointing out a security leak in my current setup?

Comment: Suggestion for a working solution. The tl;dr is that Certificate Manager-issued certs can only be used on certain pieces of AWS infrastructure, like ELBs; you can't put them on arbitrary web servers you manage.

Comment: @DylanSp alright. If that's the case, I would consider another solution than CM. The solution is for a public mobile app, so no connection should be HTTP.

Comment: The only HTTP connection would be internal to AWS's infrastructure, between the load balancer and your server. The connection from the mobile app to the load balancer would be HTTPS.

Comment: @DylanSp that's interesting. I understood you would disable HTTPS from the Load Balancer. How could you solve it like that then?

Comment: I'll type up an answer describing it. :)

Comment: Do you have the solution for this? I have the exact problem but on Laravel.

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth it has been a few years and the project got stuck a few weeks after this. But I'm pretty sure I managed to make this part work and I'm also pretty sure that the solution was based on the answer by DylanSp below. Attach an Elastic Load Balancer and configure the SSL to this and then keep the connection between the load balancer and the server in plain HTTP.

Comment: @SimonDegn does that mean you made the `options` blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, certificates created through AWS Certificate Manager can only be used for [certain AWS services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html) such as Elastic Load Balancers, not self-managed web servers. What you can do is use a Certificate Manager cert and put it on a load balancer, with your Apache/Node server sitting behind the load balancer in a target group. All connections over the public internet would be HTTPS, but the connection between the load balancer and your app server (going over AWS's internal network) would be plain HTTP.

[image: Diagram of HTTPS connections from clients to the Elastic Load Balancer and HTTP connections from the load balancer to EC2 instances]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try it out and let you know how it works :-)

Comment: How should I do this? Do it in apache/nginx? in amazon dashboard? Any advice would be  very helpful